# Dock crashes on network aliases to offline server

Tags: network, dock, macos

I have several shortcuts to network folders in my dock. Since I'm running El Capitan, the Dock crashes and will not restart properly after killing it when those network connections are not available (the server is either off, or I'm on another netowork).

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds? I can't find any related topics.

Comment: What happens when you recreate the network shortcut (alias)?

Comment: I can't do that while the server is down. When the server is back up, the Dock will start functioning again.

All i can do is clear the Dock's preferences and then the Dock will function as expected. However, i would just like to keep my aliases whether they work or not. Just as it functioned in any other version of OSX.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I removed the passwords and the servers from the Keychain access.

And El Capitan doesn't try anymore to auto-connect to the servers.

This in not the perfect solution because I have to tape the password each time, but for now, it's better.

Answer (score -1):

First solution, not the best, but it's works for me.

If the passwords are not in memory, the servers are not auto-mounted !

Comment: I don't understand what the solution is or how this applies to my problem exactly.